# RedirectToAction does not do what I need. What are my options?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller I have something similar to this:

```
[HttoPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyViewModel myViewModel)   
{  
   //...Some logic  

   return RedirectToAction("SecondMethod", new { ... pupulating view model ... });  
}   

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SecondMethod()  
{  
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "SomeOtherController");  
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SecondMethod(MyViewModel myViewModel)  
{  
   //...Do Something
   return View("MyView", myViewModel);  
}
```

Obviously the RedirectToAction from the MyMethod action will never call the HttpPost one which is what I need. The problem is that if I do the following:

```
return SecondMethod(myViewModel);
```

instead, the URL that is displayed on the browser is **.../.../.../MyMethod** and I need it to be **.../.../.../SecondMethod**

What can I do so that I can hit the HttpPost action and have the correct URL displayed on the browser?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot redirect to POST actions. This doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: What I need does make sense. The original "MyMethod" action is a POST action (I forgot to add the attribute in the code). If some logic in the method (which for confidentiality reasons I cannot add) happens then I need to call the SecondMethod action and I really need the POST version AND to display its URL in the browser.

Comment: in this case you will have to move this logic (the one that you cannot show and which is confidential)into the second POST method and then have the view directly send a request to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a non action method and call it from `MyMethod()` and `SecondMethod()`:

```
private void DoStuff()
{
    //...Do Something
}

public ActionResult MyMethod(MyViewModel myViewModel)   
{  
   //...Some logic
   DoStuff();  

   return RedirectToAction("SecondMethod", new { ... pupulating view model ... });  
}   

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SecondMethod()  
{  
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "SomeOtherController");  
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SecondMethod(MyViewModel myViewModel)  
{  
   DoStuff();
   return View("MyView", myViewModel);  
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses either of the problems posed by the question (redirect with the viewmodel and desired URL display).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't actually need HttpPost; you just need the functionality from that method to be available in a corresponding HttpGet action that accepts an instance of `MyViewModel`, and returns a view populated by that model. Does that sound right?

If so, try something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("SecondMethod")]
public ActionResult SecondMethodWithViewModel(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    return View("MyView", myViewModel);
}
```

You can overload your actions by using the `ActionNameAttribute`, since you can't declare another method with the same signature as your HttpPost action. The `RedirectToAction()` call and URL will respect the value you set in this attribute, so you can name the method anything you want.

Comment: We DO need the post. Basically the Get method is redirecting to a different controller to prevent someone to just type the URL and access it. The functionality on the Post method should ONLY be accessible when the form is posted.

Comment: @SergioRomero Well, they'd have to both type it in, and supply something that can be bound to a `MyViewModel`. There are other ways, I'm sure, but I know you can check the `Request.IsLocal` property to validate that the request originated from the server itself. If that is false, you could redirect to an error page or whatever is appropriate. One other way is to put the view-model into temp data, redirect (to the HttpGet method), and in that method you'd check for a view-model in temp data and predicate the ActionResult that you return on whether it is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post to an action you need to POST to that action. My recommendation would be to change the method in which the action is occurring. If it's initiated by a button click, it would be simpler to have multiple forms on your page that post independently or before submitting to use JavaScript to change the action attribute of the form doing the posting.